# "Download" image and add to Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, vue.js, input

Forgive me for google translator english :)

Hello guys !

I would like to know if there is any way to "download" an image from the web and place it into an array automatically.

I have an application with Vue on the front and Node on the back, when I upload images, I save them in a static served directory, and the path to those images is registered in the mysql database.

Knowing this, I would like to give you the option to remove already registered images and add others. So I would like to put these already served images into an array as it is done with input images.

This is the code I use to get the input images:

```
getImgs(event) {
  const selectedFiles = event.target.files;
  for (let i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i += 1) {
    this.images.push(selectedFiles[i]);
  }
  this.$refs.files.value = null;
},
```

Thanks for the help you can give me.